# JSON deserialization issues

Tags: json, deserialize, casting

I have reviewed a lot of the other deserialize issues and I keep running into problems. What I have been able to gather is that if I have a response coming back with a reserved word in the JSON, I can either use the deserializeUntyped methodology or use JSON parser. I tried using JSON2Apex and was hitting the cpu limit even with next to nothing in the response. So I reverted to my Untyped solution and keep running into a type casting error as follows:

20:17:33:209 FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type String to List

It is pointing to the first line of the first for loop in the following code. For some reason it is treating the return of 'result' which is an array of objects as a string? Very confusing. Postman response further down

```
// Hoping there is a better way to do this than using Object everywhere
        Map<String, Object> deserialized = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
        List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToInsert = new List<Opportunity>();

        for(Object instance : (List<Object>)deserialized.get('result')) {
            results.add((Map<String, Object>)instance);
        }

        for(Map<String, Object> result : results) {
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();

            opp.Block_Number__c = (Integer) Integer.valueOf(result.get('blockNumber'));
            opp.Time_Stamp__c = (Datetime) Datetime.newInstance(Long.valueOf((String) result.get('timeStamp')));
            opp.Hash__c = (String) result.get('hash');
            opp.Nonce__c = (Integer) Integer.valueOf(result.get('nonce'));
            opp.Block_Hash__c = (String) result.get('blockHash');
            opp.Transaction_Index__c = (Integer) Integer.valueOf(result.get('nonce'));
            opp.From_Address__c = (String) result.get('from');
            opp.To_Address__c = (String) result.get('to');
            opp.Transaction_Amount__c = (Decimal) toEth((String) result.get('value'));
            opp.Gas_Price_in_Eth__c = (Decimal) toEth((String) result.get('gasPrice'));
            opp.isError__c = (Boolean) Boolean.valueOf(result.get('isError'));
            opp.Transaction_Rec__c = (Boolean) Boolean.valueOf(result.get('txreceipt_status'));
            opp.Input__c = (String) result.get('input');
            opp.Contract_Address__c = (String) result.get('contractAddress');
            opp.Cumulative_Gas_Used__c = (Integer) Integer.valueOf(result.get('cumulativeGasUsed'));
            opp.Gas_Used__c = (Integer) Integer.valueOf(result.get('gasUsed'));
            opp.Confirmations__c = (Integer) Integer.valueOf(result.get('confirmations'));
            opp.AccountId = accountId;

            opportunitiesToInsert.add(opp);
        }

{
"status": "1",
"message": "OK",
"result": [
    {
        "blockNumber": "10184431",
        "timeStamp": "1591074958",
        "hash": "0xbf3caa100dc0b9f46e15a940287a0e44b78cff06d0eef8a8d4d5e295a919bbf2",
        "nonce": "462",
        "blockHash": "0xb6380bd0c92c33a17208af6f43192ce9e580db4eb9278fd1507706650165ed1d",
        "transactionIndex": "9",
        "from": "0x88d34944cf554e9cccf4a24292d891f620e9c94f",
        "to": "0x558553d54183a8542f7832742e7b4ba9c33aa1e6",
        "value": "1000000000000000000",
        "gas": "21000",
        "gasPrice": "50000000000",
        "isError": "0",
        "txreceipt_status": "1",
        "input": "0x",
        "contractAddress": "",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "340221",
        "gasUsed": "21000",
        "confirmations": "55156"
    },
    {
        "blockNumber": "10184559",
        "timeStamp": "1591076771",
        "hash": "0xa5fe1b6b438a9d9a8f68f384f5b86814a1466464749f7681dd37a1aafb5e0161",
        "nonce": "0",
        "blockHash": "0xbb98e5ab911efed60bf3375276f0a7bd2c1f5ca144d16d9037c82f9409f6855d",
        "transactionIndex": "2",
        "from": "0x558553d54183a8542f7832742e7b4ba9c33aa1e6",
        "to": "0xefb2e870b14d7e555a31b392541acf002dae6ae9",
        "value": "998866000000000000",
        "gas": "21000",
        "gasPrice": "54000000000",
        "isError": "0",
        "txreceipt_status": "1",
        "input": "0x",
        "contractAddress": "",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "85715",
        "gasUsed": "21000",
        "confirmations": "55028"
    },
    {
        "blockNumber": "10184571",
        "timeStamp": "1591076943",
        "hash": "0xc931dbb3c6de9df1b50d48026015275236de06b5fd4fa22f0c2921cd755cebc1",
        "nonce": "1",
        "blockHash": "0x2cfab75b0245a90d8aafc61ef22afd835bff0022ca6b2b03b3cda47f1ebad1e1",
        "transactionIndex": "21",
        "from": "0xd273bd546b11bd60214a2f9d71f22a088aafe31b",
        "to": "0x558553d54183a8542f7832742e7b4ba9c33aa1e6",
        "value": "400001000000000000000000",
        "gas": "21000",
        "gasPrice": "54000000000",
        "isError": "0",
        "txreceipt_status": "1",
        "input": "0x",
        "contractAddress": "",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "862453",
        "gasUsed": "21000",
        "confirmations": "55016"
    },
    {
        "blockNumber": "10220711",
        "timeStamp": "1591560252",
        "hash": "0x3a9634bd9fb68fa9aa550ddadda5f7e034684a8c957deb7be4832c2d28d44b52",
        "nonce": "26192",
        "blockHash": "0x7485a3f3ac312d7c0746f7ed625a0e78aed11c249a83b31a4c80f4c2c50a4085",
        "transactionIndex": "103",
        "from": "0x491fe5f4724e642c90372b0b95b60c4ac8d13f1c",
        "to": "0x558553d54183a8542f7832742e7b4ba9c33aa1e6",
        "value": "1000000000000000",
        "gas": "21000",
        "gasPrice": "31824000000",
        "isError": "0",
        "txreceipt_status": "1",
        "input": "0x",
        "contractAddress": "",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "5494053",
        "gasUsed": "21000",
        "confirmations": "18876"
    }
]
```

}

I've gone back and forth on this quite a bit with the latest attempt being the first for loop you see above in an effort to properly cast the list of transactions.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Also, many of those casts are not necessary. Integer.valueOf, for example, is already an Integer and does not need to be cast again.

Comment: First line of the first ‘for’ loop. I know some casts are unnecessary, just haven’t bothered to remove them yet.

Comment: Okay, so I copy-pasted your JSON to a string, and copied the first few lines of code, and ran it in exec anon... it runs fine. Check your results by debugging them or capturing them in a file somewhere. You might be getting the wrong response.

Comment: You nailed it but now I'm having a different problem. I'll post a follow up question.

Comment: so much easier to just use `theJson = theJson.replace('"reservedword":','"reservedwordX":');` to preprocess the JSON then you can use `JSON.deserialize(theJson,List<CustomType>.class)` directly into a list of custom types with a property appended with X so as to avoid.